# cakephp - one find() query to rule them all

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following model relationships defined:

```
class Publication extends AppModel {

    var $name = 'Publication';

    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Author'=>array(
            'className'=>'Author'
        )
    );     
}

class Author extends AppModel {

    var $name = 'Author';

    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Publication'=>array(
            'className'=>'Publication'
        )
    );

    var $belongsTo = array(
        'College' => array (
            'className' => 'College'
        )
    );      
}

class College extends AppModel {

    var $name = 'College';

var $hasMany = array(
        'Department'=>array(
            'className'=>'Department'
        )
    );      
}

class Department extends AppModel {

    var $name = 'Department';

var $belongsTo = array(
        'College'=>array(
            'className'=>'College'
        )
    );      
}
```

The database tables are set up correctly (join tables for the HABTM, etc.).  I am trying to find the one DB query to rule them all.  I want to create a query that will find all of the publications with the associated authors, colleges, departments, etc.  After getting data from a form, I have tried to run queries like this:

```
 $conditions = array(
            "Author.id" => $this->data['authors'],
            "Publication.year" => $this->data['year']                                
            );
$publications = $this->Publication->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions));
```

This throws SQL errors saying that Author.id is not a valid field.  Now, this is because a join with the 'authors' db table has not been completed by the time Author.id is being searched for.  BUT, if I do this:

```
$pubs = $this->Publication->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions));
```

then I get an array that has all of the Publications with all of the associated Authors (though, not the associated Colleges for some reason).

My question is this:  what do I need to do to make the tables join before Author.id is searched for?  I've attempted to use bindModel, containable, subqueries, but cannot get those to work for some reason (probably a ID10T error).

Thanks for any advice!

Edit:
The result of the following call:

```
$this->Publication->recursive = 2;
$pubs = $this->Publication->find('all');
```

are as follows:

```
Array (
```

[0] => Array ( 
    [Publication] => Array ( [id] => 1 [title] => TestArticle [year] => 2011 [type_id] => 3 ) 
    [Type] => Array ( [id] => 3 [type_name] => Journal Articles ) 
    [Author] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( [id] => 2 [firstname] => Jeremy [lastname] => Gustine [middle] => A [faculty] => 0 [college_id] => 4                 [AuthorsPublication] => Array ( [id] => 3 [author_id] => 2 [publication_id] => 1 ) 
            [College] => Array ( [id] => 4 [college_name] => Letters, Arts, and Sciences ) ) 
        [1] => Array ( [id] => 3 [firstname] => George [lastname] => Obama [middle] => A [faculty] => 0 [college_id] => 6               [AuthorsPublication] => Array ( [id] => 2 [author_id] => 3 [publication_id] => 1 ) 
            [College] => Array ( [id] => 6 [college_name] => School of Public Affairs ) ) 
        [2] => Array ( [id] => 2 [firstname] => Jeremy [lastname] => Gustine [middle] => A [faculty] => 0 [college_id] => 4                 [AuthorsPublication] => Array ( [id] => 1 [author_id] => 2 [publication_id] => 1 ) 
            [College] => Array ( [id] => 4  [college_name] => Letters, Arts, and Sciences ) ) ) ) 
[1] => Array ( 
    [Publication] => Array ( [id] => 2 [title] => TestBook [year] => 2010 [type_id] => 1 ) 
    [Type] => Array ( [id] => 1 [type_name] => Books ) 
    [Author] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( [id] => 7 [firstname] => Sony [lastname] => Stuff [middle] => L [faculty] => 0 [college_id] => 5             [AuthorsPublication] => Array ( [id] => 4 [author_id] => 7 [publication_id] => 2 ) 
            [College] => Array ( [id] => 5 [college_name] => Nursing and Health Science ) ) ) ) )

Hopefully that is somewhat readable...

Comment: Shouldn't College have many Authors?

Comment: Now that you mention it, yes I think it should.  Although even without that association defined in the College model, I am able to find the associated Colleges with a publication now that I am using Rikesh's advice below.

Answer (score 1):

Your second find is correct

i.e. `$pubs = $this->Publication->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions));`

just above that try using recursive 2 (below code) to get related `College` too.

`$this->Publication->recursive = 2;`

Comment: Excellent, that does help me find the associated Colleges.  Thanks!  But, I am still unable to filter the results by Author.  When I apply the conditions that I specified in my original question, I still get a "Unknown column 'Author.id' in 'where clause'" because the join with the Author table has not yet occurred.  Any ideas there?

Comment: Strange it should work.Can you `print_r` your output removing that condition.

Comment: I edited the question to included the requested information.  Sorry about the ugly format....seems the 'code' tag didn't cover it all.